# Error when running "npm install" against a root directory to compile

Tags: node.js, angular, vagrant

I'm trying to setup a vagrant environment for running the angular-2 cli...

This is my Vagranfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config| 
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

    config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrant-provision-npm-angular-2.sh"

end
```

This is my vagrant-provision-npm-angular-2.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "prereqs install openssl"
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0

echo "prereqs install ntp"
sudo apt-get install ntp -y
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpd -gq
sudo service ntp start

echo "prereqs install curl"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install curl -y

echo "install zip"
sudo apt-get install unzip

echo "create directory"
mkdir /downloads -p
pushd /downloads

echo "install python 2.7"
sudo apt-get install python2.7 -y

echo "get pip"
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py 

echo "execute get-pip.py"
sudo python get-pip.py
popd

echo "install aws cli"
sudo pip install awscli

echo "install nodejs"
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

echo "update npm"
npm install npm@latest -g

echo "intall angular cli (beta- require Node 4 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher)"
npm install -g angular-cli
```

Everything seems to install ok, but when I vagrant ssh to run "npm install" against a root directory to compile, I get the following error:

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ sudo npm install

> ng2-uploader@1.5.7 postinstall /vagrant/node_modules/ng2-uploader
> ngc -p tsconfig.json

Error: Error Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
    at Object.check (/vagrant/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc.js:31:15)
    at Object.main (/vagrant/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/main.js:26:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/main.js:16:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
Compilation failed
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.2 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.2 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ng2-uploader@1.5.7 postinstall: `ngc -p tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ng2-uploader@1.5.7 postinstall script 'ngc -p tsconfig.json'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ng2-uploader package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ngc -p tsconfig.json
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ng2-uploader
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ng2-uploader
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/npm-debug.log
```

Update: I think this might be related to Angular-cli not installing correctly... (still don't know how to fix this)

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ ng help
Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-common.js:7:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/models/index.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-config.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/build-webpack.js:6:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/build.js:3:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Class.includedCommands (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/index.js:21:16)
    at /vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:392:61
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Project.addonCommands (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:391:15)
    at Project.eachAddonCommand (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:426:30)
    at module.exports (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/cli/lookup-command.js:33:13)
    at CLI.<anonymous> (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:34:26)
    at tryCatch (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/-internal.js:215:12)
    at invokeCallback (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/-internal.js:230:13)
    at publish (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/-internal.js:198:7)
    at flush (/vagrant/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/asap.js:85:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that vagrant has run your provisioning script as root user so everything has been installed but for the root user, while you want the tool to be available under the `vagrant` user.

Make the following change in your Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

    config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrant-provision-npm-angular-2.sh", privileged: "false"

end
```

Note once you are in the VM (`vagrant ssh`) that you do not need to run `sudo npm install` just running `npm install` is enough

Comment: I made the change to the Vagrantfile, but I am still getting the same error...  did the Vagrantfile work for you?

Comment: yes it worked for me - I cloned https://github.com/AngularShowcase/angular2-sample-app and was able to run `npm install` ... did you reprovision after your made the change (run `vagrant provision` to run the provisioning again and make sure it does not fail, if it fails, just destroy the VM and create a new one)

Comment: I am not sure why you keep running your commands with `sudo` you dont need sudo priviliegies, if you need to run with sudo it means you did not run the provisioning correctly. running `npm install` for the sample project just works `vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/angular2-sample-app$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated es6-module-loader@0.17.11: This project has been deprecated for "npm install es-module-loader" based on the newer loader spec.
npm WARN deprecated gulp-minify-css@1.2.4: Please use gulp-clean-css
npm WARN deprecated tsd@0.6.5: TSD is deprecated in favor of Typings (https://githu....`